# How to write a typed flatten method for an array

Tags: typescript, type-inference, type-systems

I am trying to write something in TypeScript similar to *[Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)*.

However, I want to be able to flatten a nested list of arbitrary depth; and also I want to restrict all non-array elements to a single type.

Something like:

```js
interface NestedList<T> extends Array<T | NestedList<T>> {}
```

I have got this so far:

```js
export const flat = <T>(ls: NestedList<T>): T[] => {
   const reducer = (acc: T[], it: T | NestedList<T>): T[] => acc.concat(
      Array.isArray(it) ? it.reduce(reducer, []) : it
   );

   return ls.reduce(reducer, []);
};
```

However, the type inference does not seem to be working:

```
   it('works with type inference', () => {
      interface Foo<T> { v: T; }

      const data: { [_: string]: { [_: string]: Foo<number> } } = {
         bar: { x: { v: 1 } },
         moo: { y: { v: 2 }, z: { v: 3 } }
      };

      const nested: Foo<number>[][] = Object.values(data).map(val => Object.values(val));
      const list2: Foo<number>[] = flat(nested);
      expect(list2).toEqual([{ v: 1 }, { v: 2 }, { v: 3 }]);
   });
```

It receives a type error on this line:

```js
const list2: Foo<number>[] = flat(nested);
```

Error:

```
Type '(Foo<number>[] | ConcatArray<Foo<number>[]>)[]' is not assignable to type 'Foo<number>[]'.
  Type 'Foo<number>[] | ConcatArray<Foo<number>[]>' is not assignable to type 'Foo<number>'.
    Property 'v' is missing in type 'Foo<number>[]' but required in type 'Foo<number>'
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Take a look at how `--lib esnext.array` does it: [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.esnext.array.d.ts)

Comment: It seems to be limiting the depth. Is this a fundamental limitation of the type system?

Comment: Ultimately, yes. The type system can *theoretically* express the concept of 'arbitrarily nested arrays' but it runs into problems with recursively defined types around 23 nestings (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54988812/1715579)). The strategy TypeScript's own engineers use it to define the most common use cases with the type system, and rely on the user to provide hints/assertions for more unusual cases.

Comment: In trying to understand why this happens, I found it in the simpler case of:
```
const foo = (bar: <T>(l: NestedList<T>) => T, baz: string[]): string => bar<string>(baz);
```
This compiles but fails without the `<string>`.

I still don't understand why, but I thought it might make it easier for others to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on the same problem as you. This is the solution I came up with:

```js
function flat<U>(arr: U[][]): U[] {
    if ((arr as unknown as U[]).every((val) => !Array.isArray(val))) {
        return (arr as unknown as U[]).slice();
    }
    return arr
        .reduce((acc, val) => acc
            .concat(Array.isArray(val) ? flat((val as unknown as U[][])) : val), []);
}

console.log(flat([[1,2],[[[3]]],4])
```